# Passport session disappears after oauth callback

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ionic-framework, passport.js

Making a hybrid app with Ionic, Angular, nodejs, etc.

User logs in with email and password and then wants to add 3rd party authentication to their account.
They are serialized into session.
We check, using passport, if they are authorized with 3rd party and if not send them to do so.
When the user comes back to the callback url we don't know who they are anymore because req.session is undefined.

Edit: I've been trying to simplify the code to get to the route of the problem.

```
// require everything and app.use them
// this is what I'm using for the session config
app.use(session({
    secret: 'thisIsASecret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,   
    cookie: {secure: true, maxAge: (4*60*60*1000)}
}));

var user = {  // simple user model for testing
    id: 1,
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
    oauthId: null
};

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    done(err, user);
});

// Local Passport
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    return done(null, user);
}));
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session);  // Prints out session object with passport.user = 1
    res.end();
});

// oauth Passport
passport.use(new oauthStrategy({
    clientID: ****,
    clientSecret: ****,
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/oauth/callback',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    console.log(req.session);  // no passport object in session anymore
    return done(null, profile);
}));
app.get('/auth/oauth', passport.authorize('oauth'));
app.get('/auth/oauth/callback', passport.authorize('oauth'), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.session);  // no passport object in session here either
    res.end();
});
```

On the client side after logging in I use this because the regular http request method doesn't work.

```
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/oauth';
```

Edit 2: Ionic doesn't allow sessions apparently. So I found that you can use the `state` parameter to send a token with the oauth request which comes back to the callback and use that to link the oauth details to the user's account.

```
app.get('auth/oauth/:token', function(req, res) {
    passport.authorize('oauth', {state: req.params.token});
});
```

The only problem is now it won't redirect to the 3rd party to authorize with them. Just times out...

Comment: Could you please provide a piece of code?

Comment: @VinceOPS Added code to the question. This is a simple as I could make it. Still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use the route like this, where `token` is used to identify the user.

```
app.get('auth/oauth/:token', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authorize('oauth', {state: req.params.token})(req, res, next);
});
```

Then the token was available in the callback (`req.query.state`) and we can add the new details to our existing user details.